# getComputedStyle() height and width property return pure CSS instead of values in CSSStyleDeclaration object

Tags: javascript, css

I am getting the width and height of an image styled with CSS in my JavaScript using `window.getComputedStyle(img,null)` where `img` is my image.

The image that is being processed is declared in a Soy template as follows:

```
<img class="diffImg" id="diff-{$key}" style="display:block; margin-left: auto; width: 80%; height:auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 10px;" src="my-source">
```

There are several images on the page, displayed in a tabbed view. Each tab is defined like this:

```
<li class="menu-item">
 <a id="{$key}" href="#tab-{$key}" onclick="changeWheelzoom(this)">{$diffImage[$key].name}</a>
</li>
```

The JavaScript code in the `onclick` function that processes the image:

```
var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(img, null);
width = parseInt(computedStyle.width, 10);
height = parseInt(computedStyle.height, 10);
console.log(computedStyle);
console.log(computedStyle.width.valueOf() + ' ' + computedStyle.height.valueOf());
```

Here is where I encounter a roadblock. After running `getComputedStyle` I get a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object that contains the value of the image's width and height in pixels, which I can see in the console. Accessing the `computedStyle.width` and `computedStyle.height` properties, however, returns the pre-processed values that were specified in the CSS (`80%` and `auto`), after which `parseInt` fails to provide accurate information.

The following is logged in the console:

```
CSSStyleDeclaration{ (second console.log)
...
height: "469.031px"
...
width: "740.797px"
...
}

80% auto (second console.log)
```

Why does the console output differ from what I get in the program and how can I solve this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Alright. Give me a moment, I'll update the question.

Comment: @YongQuan I have clarified some things. I don't know if I can make the problem reproducible for you, as this is a part of a bigger framework (Atlassian SDK) and I cannot extract the same html classes to use without it.